# Detecting which values have been added and removed from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script that has two arrays, the initial data array (`$initial`), and the modified data array (`$modified`), but I have hit an issue in detecting the differences between the arrays. I need to determine which values (the keys will be different between them) have been added, and which values have been removed and place the changes into two arrays afterward (`$dataAdded` and `$dataRemoved`).

Are there any functions available to do this, or if not, are there any concepts that I could follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_diff()](http://docs.php.net/function.array-diff) can do that.

```
<?php
$initial = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$modified = foo($initial);

$removed = array_diff($initial, $modified);
$added = array_diff($modified, $initial);

echo 'removed=', join(', ', $removed), "\n";
echo 'added=', join(', ', $added), "\n";

function foo($a) {
    // "removing" all odd numbers
    // and "adding" 10,12,14,16
    return array_map(function($e) { return $e*2; }, $a);
}
```

prints

```
removed=1, 3, 5, 7
added=10, 12, 14, 16
```

Comment: That goes by keys, and the keys will be changing as the positions of the entries in the arrays may be different, but it only needs the existence of the value to be the existing/non-existant

Comment: Nice, will that be faster than my method (certainly cleaner)?

Comment: I did a little synthetic test and, yes, array_diff() was consistently faster, by a factor of 7-8, using `$initial = range(1,20000)` and the same `function foo()` as in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to cancel the question, but I felt there might be useful to others having a similar problem, or if there is something foolish in here that I have missed, but anyway:

I used the following:

```
$dataAdded = array();
$dataRemoved = array();
foreach ($modified as $data) {
    if (!in_array($data, $initial)) {
        $dataAdded[] = $data;
    }
}
foreach ($initial as $data) {
    if (!in_array($data, $modified)) {
        $dataRemoved[] = $data;
    }
}
```